# MPI_Win_allocate() does not return

Tags: c++, c, mpi, mpi-rma

When I run the following code with `mpirun -n 2 ./out` it works with no problem but with `mpirun -n 3 ./out` `MPI_Win_allocate()` does not return. I checked this out by printing to the screen before and after `MPI_Win_allocate()`. Also, if I comment out `MPI_Bcast()` the code works. What is the problem?

EDIT: Changed boost functions to standard ones to simplify the problem.

```
#include <mpi.h>

int main()
{
    MPI_Init(NULL, NULL);

    int nmesh;
    MPI_Bcast(&nmesh, 1, MPI_INT, 0, MPI_COMM_WORLD);         

    MPI_Win win;
    int* narrival;
    MPI_Win_allocate(1*sizeof(int), sizeof(int), MPI_INFO_NULL, MPI_COMM_WORLD, &narrival, &win);
    MPI_Win_free(&win);

    MPI_Finalize();

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: I'm not familiar with the boost interface to MPI, but to me it looks like you haven't initialised the communicator world. Should you not have world=MPI_COMM_WORLD before the broadcast call?

Comment: Adding `MPI_Barrier()` right after `MPI_Bcast()` solved the freezing of `MPI_Win_allocate()` but I do not know why.

Comment: I have no problem running the code using OpenMPI on an Ubuntu laptop - what system are you using?

Comment: OpenMPI 2.0.1, Ubuntu, Intel i3 processor.